# The Stack Overflow "Ask Wizard" option keeps crashing my page

Tags: support, bug, ask-question-wizard

[image]

Is it the "Ask Wizard" causing this? I can't turn it off.

I am using Google Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (x86_64) on a [MacBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) (OS Version 12.6).

Comment: This is the Ask wizzard indeed. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: @Luuklag I'm on Safari now, and it's not crashing. The only problem is that "Post your public question" is perpetually grayed out. I turned off the wizard, so I'm going to go back on Chrome and see if it's still an issue.

Comment: Now it's telling me I can only post every 90 minutes and isn't letting me publish my question. I love this site

Comment: @Dan well it refers to your question here. Why didn't you post it on Meta Stack Overflow? Ask Wizard is SO only.

Comment: What browser, and version of said browser, are you using?

Comment: @Larnu Google chrome (latest version) on Macbook (version 12.6).

Comment: Rather than stating "latest version" actually state the version; far too many times here (on [so] at least) I've seen "latest version" to mean "A completely unpatched version of the prior release".

Comment: @Larnu google chrome - Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your extensions (after waiting the 90 minutes, of course)? Looks like you have a lot, and they could easily be causing conflicts.

Comment: That isn't actually the latest version then, @Dan . The latest release is 107.0.5304.63, which was released yesterday.

Comment: Google Chrome 106 was released at least 45 days ago. `106.0.5249.119` was released on Oct 11. While it is/was an extended stable released Chrome 107 was promoted to the stable branch yesterday. Just want to highlight that @Larnu was spot on to question what version exactly you were using.

Comment: I also tried the Ask Wizard page on the latest Chrome for Mac and there's no error at all. I only have 2 extensions though.

Comment: Do you have any userscripts running? I've had similar problems with the stacks editor while SOX userscript is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue on Edge 107.0.1418.42. If I had multiple SO tabs opened, and in one I opened "ask question" page, it'd freeze **all** SO tabs!

In my case the cause was [StackExchangeNotifications](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackexchangenotification/jcjhifljlkmoodmebfiimpoofdehnhia?hl=en) ([Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/stackexchangenotification/lghbdnpkdcibhhdmfdbnekaffdliiadb)) extension.

Disabled it and SO tabs no longer freeze.